# "Mach ich" vs "Ich werde es machen"

Tags: word-usage, word-order, verb-usage

I just called a friend, to tell her she should do something, and her answer was:

> Mach ich. Danke dir.

I would have expected `Ich werde es machen`, but this answer is weird. On one side, it completely misses the suffix for the 1st person singular, on the other hand, it uses the word order for questions.

Can someone explain me this way of expressing?

Comment: In English, we might say "Will do", with a similar disregard for formal grammar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your friend used a colloquial form of expressing that he will do it. Note that the second sentence also misses a subject, which is not normally possible in German.

Regarding the word order, you can imagine an omitted demonstrative pronoun:

> Das mache ich.

The missing 'e' is common in colloquial speech. In writing this can be indicated by an apostrophe:

> Mach' ich.

Last, it is common in German to express future events using the present tense.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use an apostrophe. Duden at least doesn't use apostrophe for missing -e in some verbforms, e.g. "Das hör ich gern" (http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph)

Comment: @Iris, if it is an accepted variant, do not put the apostrophe, otherwise do.

Comment: +1. I like to add this short form is also possible with the verbs *sein*, *werden*, *tun*, *können*, *wollen*, *mögen*, *holen*, *lesen* and a few more.